# joint_trajectory_action question

Tags: ros, joint-trajectory-controller, joint-trajectory-action, trajectory-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am reading the joint_trajectory_action.cpp file in joint_trajectory_action ros package.

I have a question about following callback function.

```
void goalCB(GoalHandle gh)
{
  // Ensures that the joints in the goal match the joints we are commanding.
  if (!setsEqual(joint_names_, gh.getGoal()->trajectory.joint_names))
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Joints on incoming goal don't match our joints");
    gh.setRejected();
    return;
  }

  // Cancels the currently active goal.
  if (has_active_goal_)
  {
    // Stops the controller.
    trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory empty;
    empty.joint_names = joint_names_;
    pub_controller_command_.publish(empty);

    // Marks the current goal as canceled.
    active_goal_.setCanceled();
    has_active_goal_ = false;
  }

  gh.setAccepted();
  active_goal_ = gh;
  has_active_goal_ = true;

  // Sends the trajectory along to the controller
  current_traj_ = active_goal_.getGoal()->trajectory;
  pub_controller_command_.publish(current_traj_);
}
```

I don't understand why it needs to cancel the currently active goal.

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64155/joint_trajectory_action-question/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This action server implements a goal policy in which only *one goal* is active and *new goals preempt previous goals*, ie. it always executes the latest received goal.

In this context, "Cancels the currently active goal" means canceling the trajectory that was being executed *prior* to the goal that woke up the goalCB callback. Note that the currently active goal is *not* the goal that that woke up the goalCB callback.

Since what remains of the currently active goal won't be executed, it makes sense to cancel it, providing clients with feedback that allows them to take proper action, if needed.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-06-03**:
Very clear! Thanks!